# How to implement ed25519 algorithm into jwt using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt, ed25519

I'm trying to code an API client, the API authentication need a signing the payload using `ed25519` according to JWT specification.

**The payload is:**

```
{"key": "cnc6666666666666", "iat": 1599999999}
```

The Seed (also called Private Key, which can be used to calculate the Signing Key) of `ed25519` is:

```
"CNC88888888888888888888888888888"
```

The target(JWT Spec) result should be:

```
eyJhbGciOiJFZDI1NTE5IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTk5OTk5OTksImtleSI6ImNuYzY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjYifQ.RJzhQwRI6g0YZg-Mh201G7aEGcpxm8vN8wf-rgpK6UySeMKRgUHzZV6WLxc93PptrKNb4CLW8XQo48OYR-stDw
```

I've followed the method showed [here](https://github.com/nanlong/vnpy/blob/master/vnpy/api/chaince/vnchaince.py). The `generateSignature` function is what I've tried.

This method is not working for python3, and `ed25519` is not officially supported by JWT, so the algorithm is customized implemented in the above sample.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you [learn how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around here. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Usage: Issuing and using credentials
An Ed25519 public/private key pair needs to be created, for example using the Python cryptography package:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ed25519 import Ed25519PrivateKey
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, NoEncryption, PrivateFormat, PublicFormat

private_key = Ed25519PrivateKey.generate()
print(private_key.private_bytes(encoding=Encoding.PEM, format=PrivateFormat.PKCS8, encryption_algorithm=NoEncryption()))
print(private_key.public_key().public_bytes(encoding=Encoding.PEM, format=PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo))
```

The issuer of credentials would use the private key to create a JWT for a database user, such as in the below Python example for the database user my_user for the next 24 hours.

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
import json
import time
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

def b64encode_nopadding(to_encode):
    return urlsafe_b64encode(to_encode).rstrip(b'=')

private_key = load_pem_private_key(
    # In real cases, take the private key from an environment variable or secret store
    b'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n' \
    b'MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEINQG5lNt1bE8TZa68mV/WZdpqsXaOXBHvgPQGm5CcjHp\n' \
    b'-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n', password=None, backend=default_backend())
header = {
    'typ': 'JWT',
    'alg': 'EdDSA',
    'crv': 'Ed25519',
}
payload = {
    'sub': 'my_user',
    'exp': int(time.time() + 60 * 60 * 24),
}
to_sign = b64encode_nopadding(json.dumps(header).encode('utf-8')) + b'.' + b64encode_nopadding(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8'))
signature = b64encode_nopadding(private_key.sign(to_sign))
jwt = (to_sign + b'.' + signature).decode()
print(jwt)
```